# In-memory GUI session for UI automation

Tags: linux, automation, selenium, ui-automation

I'm automating web-UI testing using Selenium. All our existing non-UI related tests are executed through CLI by SSHing into the machine, and it would be great if there's a way to execute these UI tests through CLI by having an X-session run in memory. Is there such a thing in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, its called xfvb.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can run a VNC server and have your browser display on that. Like so

```
noufal@sanitarium% vncserver
Warning: sanitarium:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X1-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server sanitarium:1

New 'X' desktop is sanitarium:2

Starting applications specified in /home/noufal/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/noufal/.vnc/sanitarium:2.log

noufal@sanitarium% /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=sanitarium:2 /usr/bin/firefox --ProfileManager --no-remote
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "sanitarium:2.0".
```

will run a browser on the VNC

If you want to see it, you can do something like

```
noufal@sanitarium% vncviewer sanitarium:2
```